# Swift: Disable symbols on Phone pad

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I'm trying to disable symbols(+, *, #) on phone pad either programmatically or from storyboard. I have been searching for useful resources online but wasn't successful.

Is there any better way to get this done?

**EDIT**

I'm using a UITextField for which I have set the keyboard type to Phone pad.

Comment: Provide more context. Is this for a `UITextField`? Are you setting the keyboard type to "PhonePad"? Use "NumberPad" instead.

Comment: Are you using a text view or text field? Have you tried using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` to prevent those characters from typing?

Comment: @rmaddy I have edited my post. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I have edited my post. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @rmaddy Number pad has alphabets but I don't want to have alphabets or letters. I need only the numbers that means I have to use Phone pad with no symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the "Phone Pad" keyboard but you don't want the phone pad symbols. The solution is simple - don't use the "Phone Pad" keyboard. Use the "Number Pad" keyboard instead.

Keep in mind though that users can use external keyboards or they can paste text into the text field. So you can't rely on the keyboard to ensure that only certain characters are entered into the field.

You must also do proper validation by implementing the appropriate `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`.

Comment: Number pad has alphabets but I don't want to have alphabets or letters, I need only the numbers that means I have to use Phone pad with no symbols.

Comment: The number pad shows the letters under the numbers but the user can't enter those letters through the keypad. That's much better than using the phone pad which has keys you don't want.